# Why does first php echo indent(tab)?

Tags: php, html, regex

[image]

I know how to use \t and \n to make the source look pretty. However, as you can see something mysterious is happening to my first anchor tag aka the first think I'm echoing. I'm in chrome if that matters.

```
for ( $counter = 0; $counter <= sizeof($projectImages)-1; $counter += 1) {
    echo '<a href="#">'."\n";
    echo '<img class="sidebar-image" src="#">'."\n";
    echo '</a>'."\n";
}
```

Comment: I think you have  got two tabs before `for(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't shared your complete code, but it is probably a case that you have:

```
        <?php
        for ( $counter = 0; $counter <= sizeof($projectImages)-1; $counter += 1) {
```

and not:

```
<?php
        for ( $counter = 0; $counter <= sizeof($projectImages)-1; $counter += 1) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you have some tabs and/or spaces before `<?php`.

Answer (score 1):

The whitespace originates somewhere else. You'll have to look at the preceeding code to find out. It's pretty likely that you have something like this in some template:

```
...</div>
               <?php
```